# ¿Cómo mostrar varias cuentas atrás con setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript

Tengo almacenados en un vector unos valores que representan segundos y necesito hacer cuenta atrás de esos valores mostrándolos a la vez

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona correctamente para mostrar una cuenta atrás

```js
 var a = [];
 var b = {segundos: 5, elemento: 'demo1'};
 a.push(b);
 b = {segundos: 7, elemento: 'demo2'};
 a.push(b);

 var i=0;
 function MiFuncionJS()
 {
  if(a[i].segundos>0)
  {
   document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = a[i].segundos;
   a[i].segundos--;
   setTimeout("MiFuncionJS()", 1000);
  }
  else
   document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
 }
 MiFuncionJS();
```

```html
<span id="demo1"></span><br>
<span id="demo2"></span><br>
```

Pero lo que quiero es mostrar varias cuentas a la vez, dependiendo de los valores almacenados, para ello meto la función dentro de un for, como en el siguiente código

```js
 var a = [];
 var b = {segundos: 5, elemento: 'demo1'};
 a.push(b);
 b = {segundos: 7, elemento: 'demo2'};
 a.push(b);
  
   for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
 {
  (function(i)
  {
   function MiFuncionJS()
   {
    if(a[i].segundos>0)
    {
     document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = a[i].segundos;
     a[i].segundos--;
     setTimeout("MiFuncionJS()", 1000);
    }
    else
     document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
   }
   MiFuncionJS();
  })(i);
 }
```

```html
<span id="demo1"></span><br>
<span id="demo2"></span><br>
```

Pero con esto sólo consigo que muestre los datos una vez...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando pasas un parámetro como cadena a `setTimeout()`, ésta será evaluada en el momento que se acabe el temporizador, por lo que llegado el momento la llamada se realizará en un ámbito (`window`) en el que no está definida la función que creaste dentro del [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Deberás pasar como parámetro la propia función creada de la manera que te indico a continuación:

```js
var a = [
  { segundos: 5, elemento: 'demo1' },
  { segundos: 7, elemento: 'demo2' },
];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    var MiFuncionJS = function() {
      if (a[i].segundos > 0) {
        document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = a[i].segundos;
        a[i].segundos--;
        setTimeout(MiFuncionJS, 1000);
      } else {
          document.getElementById(a[i].elemento).innerHTML = "Cuenta finalizada";
          console.log("Final de:", a[i]);
      }
    }
    MiFuncionJS();
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<span id="demo1"></span><br />
<span id="demo2"></span><br />
```

Además, `setTimeout()` tiene el problema de no ser tan preciso con el paso del tiempo como `setInterval()` ya que el primero va acumulando el tiempo de ejecución y el segundo se va adaptando para mantener la periodicidad configurada ejecutando varias veces seguidas la función si por algún motivo no se pudieron ejecutar llegado el momento. Te recomiendo que sigas usando `setInterval()`.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias

Comment: Buenas... he comprobado que también funcionaría si la línea **var MiFuncionJS = function()** la cambio por **function MiFuncionJS()**. Hay alguna diferencia?

Comment: Aunque funcionalmente son casi iguales (crear una función crea una variable con el nombre de la función de manera automática) existen sutiles diferencias entre ambas. Puedes consultar extensamente el funcionamiento de las funciones y las diferencias entre un método y otro en la documentación): [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Constructor_vs._declaration_vs._expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Constructor_vs._declaration_vs._expression).

Comment: Hay un tercer método (no me cabía en el comentario anterior) haciendo uso del objeto [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function).

Comment: Muy bien, gracias!